# Formal powers series in $n$ indeterminates

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, formal-power-series

Let $R\ne\{0\}$ be a ring with identity and $2\leq n$ an integer.

For each $1\leq i\leq n$, let $\lambda_i:[1,n]\rightarrow R$ be the mapping for which $\lambda_i(i)=1$ and $\lambda_i(j)=0$ for $j\ne i$. Let $X_i:\mathbf{N}^n\rightarrow R$ be the mapping such that $X_i(\lambda_i)=1$ and $X_i(\alpha)=0$ for $\alpha\ne\lambda_i$.

Is it true that, for each $k\in\mathbf{N}$, we must have
$$X_i(k\lambda_i)=kX_i(\lambda_i)$$
for all $1\leq i\leq n$? I think the answer is yes, but I am struggling to prove it by induction. It holds trivially for $k=0$. Let it hold for $k$. Then
$$X_i((k+1)\lambda_i)=X_i(k\lambda_i+\lambda_i).$$
What to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k = 2$.
\begin{align*}
X_i(k \lambda_1) &= X_i(2 \lambda_i) = 0  \text{, and }  \\
k X_i(\lambda_i) &= 2 \cdot 1 = 2  \text{.}  
\end{align*}

(The first is equal to $0$ because the various $X_i$ are only nonzero for certain functions whose range is $\{0,1\}$, but $2\lambda_i(i) = 2 \not\in \{0,1\}$.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Does this imply that the $X_i$ defined as such cannot serve as the basis of $R^{\mathbf{N}^n}$? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @alf262 : If the $X_i$ are going to be a basis, you need to define them "extended by linearity".  "$X_i(\lambda_i) = 1$, $X_i(\lambda_j) = 0$ for $j \neq i$, and $X_i$ is extended by linearity."  This makes $X_i(a \lambda_i + b \lambda_j) = a X_i(\lambda_i) + b X_i(\lambda_j)$.